# How to load vuejs components in a specific order?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a parent component which contains two children components.
One of the two children components will store data in a database through an axios call.
The second child component will need to query the database to get those datas.

How can I ensure that the second one won't "start" before the first one inserted the datas ?

Should I use the custom events ?

Comment: Maybe Async Function and once its run you call the function of ur other component

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) conditional rendering with `async/await`, something like:

```
<first-component />
<second-component v-if="didFirstComponentFinish" />

data() {
  return {
    didFirstComponentFinishAjax: false
  }
}, ...
async methods: { //or where you make your AJAX call
  await yourAjaxCall

  this.didFirstComponentFinishAjax = true //after the call is finished the component will show

  // your AJAX logic
}
```

Of course pass your AJAX data through props, vuex or whatever logic you have.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use something like [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if)="dataFromFirstChild"

Example:

*HTML:*

```
<first-child></first-child>
<second-component v-if="dataFromFirstChild" >
```

*Script:*

```
data() {
   return {
      dataFromFirstChild: false
   }
},
beforeMount(): { 
    axios.get('...')
    .then(function (response){

        //now do whatever you want with the response             

        this.dataFromFirstChild = true; //render the secondChild now
    }.bind(this)))
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the child that stores the data in the database an emit to pass to the parent an event 'load', that will be triggered (and emitted) when all the functions of the data storing have been executed.

Then in the parent, capture that event and assign it a callback to have a ref to it, so we can use it with the v-if binding in the 2nd child. Therefore, when the 2nd child does the axios call, the 1st child has already done the database work (if not, 2nd child wouldn't even be created yet).

```
//Inside the 1st child:

//define emits
const emits = defineEmits(['load']);

onMounted(() => {
    //your database operations
    //...
   
    emits('load');
});

//Now on parent
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    const firstChildLoaded = ref(false);
</script>

<template>
    <FirstChild @load="firstChildLoaded = true" />
    <SecondChild v-if="firstChildLoaded" />
</template>
```

It would be possible to do this for an array of components, so we could render all of them in order using the special component  with the v-for and :is directives. This could be useful when you need to load the components of a page one after another. The only requirement is to have that 'load' emit in each of the components of the array. An example of this:

```
//code in the parent that will contain the components loaded in order
const components = reactive([
    {
        name: 'MyHeader',
        component: shallowRef(MyHeader),
        loaded: false
    },
    {
        name: 'RouterView',
        component: shallowRef(RouterView),
        loaded: false
    },
    {
        name: 'MyFooter',
        component: shallowRef(MyFooter),
        loaded: false
    },

]);
```

```
<template v-for="comp in components">

  <component 
      v-if="previousLoaded(comp.name, components)" 
      @load="components[getIndex(comp.name, components)].loaded = true" 
      :is="comp.component">
  </component>

</template>
```

With that structure, the array of components will load one after another, sequentially. This probably has a better approach but this was the solution i found for myself and wanted to share it. (My problem was that when the page did reload, the footer loaded before the other components, making the scroll make weird things and triggering some css animations via js when i didn't want)

Comment: This is an old question, not sure the op needs help anymore :p